# Export to HTML where each section is a sub-page

Tags: sectioning, tex4ht, html

I have my CV on LyX/Latex. It contains many different sections like publications, conferences, proceedings, etc. I would like to export it to HTML in order to create a website, so that each of the sections can be a sub-page of the website, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it is possible using `tex4ht`. Here is a simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}

\lipsum

\section{Another section}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It can be compiled using

```
make4ht sample.tex 2
```

The option `2` after TeX file does the trick. It specifies the sectioning level, which should be used for page splitting. Section is second level, therefore we need to use 2, levels 1-4 are supported.

The example produces three html documents, first contains table of contents, the other two are for contents of the sections.

`sample.html`:

[image]

the first section:

[image]

The links at the top can be removed if you want.

Comment: thanks a lot! Last thing, can this be integrated into LyX?

Comment: @flow I don't know about LyX, it should be possible to integrate it if it is possible to add custom compiler